# Sort logs by timestamp in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, logstash, kibana, filebeat

[Timestamps don`t match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QSaU.gif)
I have and ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana) instance running and Filebeat sending logs from other machines, and I noticed that logs are shown in Kibana in different order that they arrived to the server (as you can see in the attached picture), for example, this is what is shown in Kibana, the second column is kibana timestamp and the third column is the server timestamp:

```
February 9th 2017, 11:53:11.714 11:53:04,904
February 9th 2017, 11:53:11.714 11:53:05,579
February 9th 2017, 11:53:11.714 11:53:05,581
February 9th 2017, 11:53:11.714 11:53:05,591
February 9th 2017, 11:53:11.714 11:53:04,441
February 9th 2017, 11:53:11.714 11:53:05,589
```

What I see in the log file is:

```
11:53:04,441
11:53:04,904
11:53:05,579
11:53:05,581
11:53:05,589
11:53:05,591
```

Is there any option to see the logs in Kibana in the same order that they are shown in the server?
I was looking for it but I didn`t see any question which treat this topic, but I saw that it could be changing the Logstash configuration file 10-syslog-filter.conf, this is mine:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because you haven't given the `timestamp` on which the events should be shown in `Kibana`, when you're creating the *index* in Kibana. You can do something like this:

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "received_time" => "%{syslog_timestamp}" }
    remove_field => ["syslog_timestamp"] <-- since you'll be using the recieved_time field here after
}
date {
    match => [ "received_time", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss"]
    target => "received_time"
    locale => "en"
    timezone => "UTC"
}
```

The above is just a sample, so that you could reproduce. **Note** that I'm assuming `syslog_timestamp` as your server time which you mentioned in your Q.

So when you're creating a new index in `Kibana`, you'll be asked to select the **time-field** name in order to filter the events. What `Kibana` does is, it'll show the events based on the browser's time unless you select it from the drop down.

So once you process the *logstash* conf you should be able to see the field **received_time**  which we created in the conf in the drop down. Thus you simply have to select it from the [drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gv3N.jpg) , so that `Kibana` would show the events based on the `timestamp` you have selected. Also **make sure** that you don't have any *timezone* issues as well. If you're using `UTC`, please change the browser timezone as well from **Advanced Settings > dateFormat:tz** in `Kibana`. Hope it helps!

Comment: I checked the timestamp between ELK server and one of the servers which is sending logs and they are a bit different, could it be a problem?

Comment: What's the time difference between two of them? Is it after what you did according to my answer?

Comment: about 2 minutes

Comment: Are you sure the ELK server is running on *UTC*? Make sure both of them are having it.

Comment: All of them are running on CET

Comment: Oh then you may have to change the *timezone* in `conf` to CET and `Kibana` as well. So that there won't be any time differences.

Comment: @kendrickjohn you may have a take a look at this [thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-timezone/29270) since Kibana's default timezone sounds to be *UTC*. Let me know if it works?

Comment: I have made the change but the problem it is still there, the point is that in a bunch of 10 lines of log, they are unsorted in Kibana so I cannot follow them.

Comment: I think that Kibana's default timezone is not the problem here, it looks to be something in the configuration.

Comment: @kendrickjohn what do you mean by unsorted? You mean the entries are jumbled across the timestamp? and those 10 are not in the **order**? Are you getting the entries by the timestamp in the logs now?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the example in the Q. (I updated it), the logs are mixed and I cannot follow the trace though Kibana due to the order is different than in the original log file.

Comment: So in your server, are the logs in the correct order? Or does it look like the same? '

Comment: Yes, they are. I updated the question and now it shows the log file timestamp. It is ordered as they appear in the time.

Comment: In `Kibana` what if you sort the results by the **time** column? Are you seeing it in the correcr order? Like [this](http://imgur.com/a/qh338)

Comment: It is sorted like in your picture and it works well but it is sorting at the time  at Logstash receive the logs not at the time that logs are produced. When we have many lines of log in the sames seconds (04, 05), the bunch of logs that Filebeat sends to Logstash are sending at one second all of them together and Kibana show them unsorted. Is it clear my question?

Comment: Oops ok. Haven't worked with *filebeat* though. Wasn't aware that *filebeat* was part of this Q. Sorry about that!

Comment: I attached a picture explaining clearer the problem, just in case you can help, thanks